# Amazon sent extra book, should I return it?

Tags: internet, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

I ordered one book from Amazon, but received two (of the same). Should I return it?

Comment: If you ask about it they'll probably let you keep it if it's not too expensive a book. Then you skip the moral debate and get your books

Comment: Check your credit card bill, you probably bought 2 by mistake its happened to me just a slip of the finger...

Comment: I had a similar, but not identical, situation. I ordered the 3rd edition of a book from an amazon reseller of used books, and received the 2nd edition. I contacted the seller, and he offered to send me the new version free of charge and to keep the old version. As @DoubleAA mentioned, it is not worth it for them to pay for the shipping of the wrong book back, unless it is something very valuable.

Comment: I think you should ask a competant Orthodox rabbi for practical advice and as to whether you can keep the book without violating the prohibition of stealing. Stealing is prohibited even from a non-Jew.

Answer (score 5):

Rambam says (גזלות ואבידות יא:ד) you can rely on the non-jew’s authority in a sale, that he is in charge, and should he mess up, you’re off the hook.

Also, the rules of the country you live in (probably USA) apply, ‏דינא דמלכותא דינא. 
[Some reading on that](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/i-bought-an-item-they-charged-me-for-that-1-item-but-sent-me-two/277841/4) [also this](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0181-unordered-merchandise)
You call also trying asking on SE LAW; [someone even did.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17533/if-a-retailer-sends-you-something-you-didnt-order-can-you-keep-it)

Otherwise you may then מחלל שם שמים. Which is similarly expressed in Tosefta ([Baba Kama 10:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tosefta_Bava_Kamma.10.8?with=all&lang=bi)):

> הגוזל את הנכרי חייב להחזיר לנכרי חמור גזל הנכרי מגזל ישראל מפני חילול השם

Comment: Is 'Amazon' a non-Jew? What about third party sellers on Amazon selling through their platform (who may or may not be Jewish)?